# Homophones emerge vs immerge

Tags: homophones

I thought I understood their difference. But then I went to [this website (YourDictionary.com) with the following example sentences](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/immerge):

> Immediately after delivery, infants immerge into a world of bright
>   lights, cold medical equipment and lots of strange voices.

Hm, I would have thought that infants emerge but ok, maybe they dive into this new world. But I saw then the following example

> In recent years, studies began to immerge about the health benefits of
>   wine, including cardiovascular system improvements and decreases in
>   certain types of cancer.

That must be wrong, mustn't it?

Comment: What do you know about the definition of immerge?

Comment: Emerge: To come into view.
Immerge: To submerge or disappear, especially in a liquid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your examples use 'immerge' wrongly, where they should have used 'emerge'. Both appear to be written by a person or persons unfamiliar with English, and, indeed, meaning. For example, infants emerge into the world at the time of delivery, not "immediately after". Also, in the second example, 'began' should be 'have begun'.

The web is full of unreliable and low-quality material. That is something you should keep firmly in mind. For dictionaries I suggest you use Oxford, Cambridge, or Merriam-Webster rather than YourDictionary.

Comment: Phew. What a relief. I thought I lost it. No wonder that "alternative facts" are on the rise given the quality of resources like this website. Problem is that I found a similar misuse of "immerse" on another website, so that made me question my understanding.

Comment: By the way, _immerge_ is **very** rare. The iWeb corpus shows 135 instances, against 139 804 of _emerge_. But at least 20 of those 135 are a brand name, and I estimate at least half of the remainder are errors for _emerge_.